# Android Sporadic 401 Authentication Required Errors

Tags: android, httprequest, http-status-code-401

I'm seeing strange behavior when calling one of my php web services hosted with hostgator. Sometimes I get a 401 unauthorized response from my service. Other times it works fine. The really strange thing is that if I get a 401 from Android, and then I call the service from my laptop browser it will start working again on Android. Something about calling the service from the browser on my laptop "resets" it so that I don't get a 401 for a while on Android.

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://myurl.com/myscript.php");
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            final String str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            Log.d(TAG, str);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
        Log.d(TAG, "post executed");
    }

}.execute(null, null, null);
```

Comment: 401 means unauthorized. Is your service secured in any way? Are you on a wifi or behind a proxy that requires authentication?

Comment: I am on wifi, but my emulator that is getting the 401 is on the same connection as my laptop that the web browser is calling from.